# Plotting an image on the sides of a cube

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to display an image onto a cube. The original image should not be changed, neither in size, nor in color.
The code is as follows:

```
cdata = flip( imread('1234.jpg'), 1 );
% imshow(cdata)
cdatar = flip( cdata, 2 );
% bottom
surface([-1 1; -1 1], [-1 -1; 1 1], [-1 -1; -1 -1], ...
    'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdatar );
% top
surface([-1 1; -1 1], [-1 -1; 1 1], [1 1; 1 1], ...
    'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdata );
% font
surface([-1 1; -1 1], [-1 -1; -1 -1], [-1 -1; 1 1], ...
    'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdata );
% back
surface([-1 1; -1 1], [1 1; 1 1], [-1 -1; 1 1], ...
    'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdatar );
% left
surface([-1 -1; -1 -1], [-1 1; -1 1], [-1 -1; 1 1], ...
    'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdatar );
% right
surface([1 1; 1 1], [-1 1; -1 1], [-1 -1; 1 1], ...
    'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdata );
% E1 = 24;
% for z = 0:360
%     view(z,E1)
%     pause(0.1)
% end
view(3);
```

This is the image I want to display:

[image]

The color has been changed and and the image resized:

[image: The view result, the color has been changed]

How can I display this image on the cube without resizing or changing color?

Answer (score 2):

You explicitly plot your image on the range `[-1 1]` on every axis, i.e. it's a perfect cube. Having your image on a face of a cube will be a square, whereas your image is a rectangle. Either don't use a cube to plot it on, or zero-pad the sides to make it appear only in the middle. Calculate the ratio of your image, retain the height, pad `(height-width)/2` zeros (or ones, depending on the desired colour) on both sides to end up with a square matrix.

MATLAB used the default colour map, `parula`. Given you have a binary image, the easiest would be to define a colour map as:

```
% You might need to flip zeros and ones for the colours
my_colur_map = [0 0 0 ; 1 1 1];
figure;
surface(...)
colormap(my_colour_map)
```

In other words: create a custom colour map with only two colours: black and white.

Comment: Because the plotted image is small, I need to add offset zero in all side. How to get the difference between the cube's side (one now) and the image size, how to calculate the difference?

Comment: Is it possible to retain the size, not just ratio of the image? How to find the pixel size of the cube?